# Как сделать выбор количества отображаемых элементов на странице?

Tags: 1с, php, битрикс

Добрый день.

Как реализовать следующий функционал? Уже голову сломал.

Есть список товаров на странице (выводится через компонент). По умолчанию на странице выводится 10 шт. Нужно реализовать строку "Выводить на странице 12 24 48".

Как это сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Внимательно почитать API битрикса и все встанет на свои места, там есть в настройках компонентов, вывод выпадающих списков для кол-ва записей на странице.

**//upd**

```
$r = CIBLockElement::GetList( 
Array("ID"=>"ASC"), 
Array("IBLOCK_ID"=>***),
false, //нет групировки 
Array("nPageSize"=>количество на странице), // ну тут можно получать из GET переменной значение
Array("ID","NAME") 
);
```

Ну и значит сделать выпадающий список рядом свой, и при изменении, при выборе значения в списке делать редирект в дополнительным GET параметром.

Comment: как то не заметил в шаблонах компонента этого. Про api, смотрел но видать не туда, носом не ткнете? если у вас это под рукой.

Answer (score 2):

Код будет выглядеть примерно так: (пишу на память)

```
/* перед вызовом компонента каталога или какой вы там используете */

if $_REQUEST['per_page']:
    $_SESSION['per_page']=$_REQUEST['per_page'];
endif;

if empty($_SESSION['per_page']):
    $per_page=12;
else:
    $per_page=$_SESSION['per_page'];
endif;

/* вызов компонента */
array(....
PER_PAGE=>$per_page,  // имя ключа не помню.. сори
```

Comment: как я понял то данный код задает показ только 12 элементов?
И еще, в коде вызова компонента есть значения которое указывается пользователем? (пардон за сложность). Тоесть можно загнать переменную в это значение а в переменную передавать значения (12 24 46 и т.д.)? я в ту сторону смотрю?

Comment: да именно так это и делается